# Python - IndexError: list index out of range while running python code

Tags: python, index-error

Please I need assistance with this code. I keep getting the error message above on line 5 and 35 of the code shown below. What is wrong?

```
output = sys.argv[1]
main()
```

Comment: `sys.argv` is empty. If you want more help than that you need to post minimal but complete code example and the input.

Comment: You already have your answer, but just an additional comment - for better argument handling, look at `argparse`. If the code is going to be run from the command line a lot, then it provides a decent method for validating parameters and outputting errors if somebody passes an invalid value.

Answer (score 1):

## `sys.argv` returns:

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0]
>   is the script name

So, if you execute the script like this `python script.py` then `sys.argv[0]`  returns `script.py` which is the name of script.

As there is no other argument, hence calling `sys.argv[1]` will raises as `IndexError`

---

Now consider another scenario when you execute the script as `python script.py tom`:

In this case calling `sys.argv[1]` returns the first command line argument which is `tom`.

Hope, this helps clear your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass argument by running file name like below

```
python file_name arg1
```

then only it will work